# Make the loop work

Tags: python

How can I make the loop work? When I  give any input, for example, 1 or 2, nothing happens.

How can I solve this?

```
import os
while 1:
    os.system('cls')
    print("")
    print("1. Decimal to Binary")
    print("2. Binary to Decimal")
    print("3. Exit")
    choice = input('Input the number: ')
    if choice == "1":
        dec_to_bin()
    elif choice == "2":
        bin_to_dec()
    elif choice == "3":
        break;

def dec_to_bin():
    decimal = input('Input a number: ')
    a =  bin(decimal)[2:]
    print(a)

def bin_to_dec():
    binary = input('Input the binary: ')
    a = int('binary', 2)
    print(a)
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: This isn't your main problem, but  `a = int('binary', 2)` should be  `a = int(binary, 2)` (without the quotes). You're parsing a variable, not a string literal.

Comment: i am using the version 2.7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Python 2, you need to change `input()` to `raw_input()`. When you enter `1` at the `input()` prompt, you get back an `int`, not a string.